# How to replace a column values in one data frame based on matching value with a column of another data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame `df1` like:

| DateTime | Radiation |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2017 | 0.23 |
| 1/1/2017 | 0.23 |
| 1/2/2017 | 0.23 |
| 1/3/2017 | 0.23 |
| 2/5/2017 | NA |

I have another data frame `df2` where I have the mean value of `Radiation` grouped by `DateTime`.

I want to update the `NA` values in `df1` by the mean value from `df2` if `df2` has a matching `DateTime` value.

I can't seem to find a way to do this using Pandas.

I tried the following way:

```
merged_df = df1[df1.Radiation.isna()].merge(df2, on='DateTime', how='left')

df1[df1.Radiation.isna()].Radiation = merged_df.Radiation_y
```

But the `Radiation` value in the indices given by `df1.Radiation.isna()` doesn't seem to get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` then `fillna`:

```
# assuming df2 is indexed by `Date`:
df1['Radiation'] = df1['Radiation'].fillna(df1['Date'].map(df2['mean_Radiation']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 ways to do it:

**Way #1**: Using merge:

```python
df1.loc[df1.Radiation.isna(), 'Radiation'] = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='DateTime').Radiation_y
```

**Way #2**: Using merge restricted to rows in df1 with a null value (I think this is what OP was trying for in the code shown in the question):

```python
mask = df1.Radiation.isna()
df1.loc[mask, 'Radiation'] = ( df1.reset_index()[mask]
    .merge(df2, how='left', on='DateTime').set_index('index').Radiation_y )
```

**Way #3**: Using mask:

```python
df1.Radiation = ( df1.reset_index().set_index('DateTime').pipe(lambda x:
    x.assign(Radiation=x.Radiation.mask(x.Radiation.isna(), df2.set_index('DateTime').Radiation))
    .set_index('index')) )
```

Input / Output:

```
df1
   DateTime  Radiation
0  1/1/2017       0.23
1  1/1/2017       0.23
2  1/2/2017       0.23
3  1/3/2017       0.23
4  2/5/2017        NaN

df2
   DateTime  Radiation
0  1/3/2017       0.98
1  2/5/2017       0.99

df1 after fill
   DateTime  Radiation
0  1/1/2017       0.23
1  1/1/2017       0.23
2  1/2/2017       0.23
3  1/3/2017       0.23
4  2/5/2017       0.99
```